# Convert flink DataSet to Json in Java

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, apache-flink

I have this

```
    DataSet<String> text = env.fromElements("some some some text here");
    DataSet<Tuple2<String, Integer>> counts = text.flatMap(new LineSplitter()).groupBy(0).sum(1);

counts.print();
```

I get this output:

```
(some,3)
(text,1)
(here,1)
```

I want to convert the result to Json:

```
{
    "some": 3,
    "text": 1,
    "here": 1
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70277657/java-convert-dataset-of-tuple2-to-string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JAVA convert Dataset of Tuple2 to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70277657/java-convert-dataset-of-tuple2-to-string)

Answer (score 0):

You may try library *Josson* to generate the JSON output.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

```
JsonNode node = Josson
    .from("some some some text here")
    .getNode("split()@.toObject('key').@group(key).map(key::elements.size()).mergeObjects()");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

**Output**

```
{
  "some" : 3,
  "text" : 1,
  "here" : 1
}
```