# JAVA convert Dataset of Tuple2 to String

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-flink

I have this dataset

```
DataSet<Tuple2<String, Integer>> counts =
                // split up the lines in pairs (2-tuples) containing: (word,1)
                text.flatMap(new LineSplitter())
                // group by the tuple field "0" and sum up tuple field "1"
                .groupBy(0)
                .sum(1);
```

the

```
counts.print();
```

returns

```
(some,3)
(text,1)
(here,1)
```

I want to return it as a string in an API response but everything I tried didn't work.

Comment: What did you try, and how did it not work?

Comment: Tried to map over the dataset and convert every line to a string and in spark using DataFrame but I guess I'm doing something wrong @azurefrog

Comment: It has no answers.. @Niko and I'm still trying hopefully ill answer both questions

Comment: What do you expect as output string ? Can you add a sample in your question ?